# Can't maintain session on NSURLConnection

Tags: objective-c, ios, mobile, mobile-safari, nsurlconnection

I am trying to connect and login with my username and password by using NSURLConnection. I can make post request and also receive response but I can't maintain session. After I make my request I receive this message from the web site:

> This system requires the use of HTTP cookies to verify authorization information.
>                                        Our system has detected that your browser has disabled HTTP cookies, or does not support them.
>                                        Please refer to the Help page in your browser for more information on how to correctly configure your browser for use with this system.

My code to make connection is here:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = nil;
request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://loginsite.com"]];
[[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage]setCookieAcceptPolicy:NSHTTPCookieAcceptPolicyAlways];

NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"username=username&pass=password"];
NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setTimeoutInterval: 15];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];

_urlConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
[_urlConnection start];
```

I would be glad if someone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

they likely check the user agent header you sent . which is none in this case....

1) add a compatible header

```
    NSString *myAgent = @"SOME AGENT StRING";
    [request setValue:myAgent forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];
```

e.g. an agent string from AFNetworking

```
    #if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED
        // User-Agent Header; see http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.43
        [self setDefaultHeader:@"User-Agent" value:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@ (%@; iOS %@; Scale/%0.2f)", [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:(NSString *)kCFBundleExecutableKey] ?: [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:(NSString *)kCFBundleIdentifierKey], (__bridge id)CFBundleGetValueForInfoDictionaryKey(CFBundleGetMainBundle(), kCFBundleVersionKey) ?: [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:(NSString *)kCFBundleVersionKey], [[UIDevice currentDevice] model], [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion], ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)] ? [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale] : 1.0f)]];
    #elif __MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED
        [self setDefaultHeader:@"User-Agent" value:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@ (Mac OS X %@)", [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:(NSString *)kCFBundleExecutableKey] ?: [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:(NSString *)kCFBundleIdentifierKey], [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleShortVersionString"] ?: [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:(NSString *)kCFBundleVersionKey], [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] operatingSystemVersionString]]];
    #endif
```

**2) take the response cookies and use them in future requests to main session**

```
nextR.requestCookies = rLogin.responseCookies.mutableCopy;
```